# Как изменить иконку в кнопке "В корзину" woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Тема Storefront woocommerce. Внутри кнопки "В корзину" есть стрелочка https://ibb.co/D7vCy77. Как она реализована и как ее поменять на другую иконку?

Comment: Нашла тему в интернете, нет там такой стрелочки на кнопке добавить в корзину.

Comment: Картинка должна быть в теле вопроса.